# Recursive web download following links according to DOM criteria

Tags: python, ruby, perl, dom, download

[MSDN is a huge hierarchical doc site.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6317367/269126)

To be more precise, the content is organized in a hierarchical manner, but the URLs are not. The URL space is flat, making it look like everything is in the same directory. (In reality, there probably isn't a directory; I guess things are coming out of some other database; but that's not relevant here.)

So if you want to download part of MSDN, say, the [NMake manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd9y37ha.aspx), you can't just recursively download everything below a given directory. Because that will be all of MSDN. Too much for your hard drive and bandwith.

But you could write a script that looks at the DOM (HTML) to then follow and download only those links contained in certain navigational sections of the document, like those of CSS `class` attribute `toc_children` and `toc_siblings`, but not `toc_parent`.

What you'd need would be some downloader that allows you to say:

```
$webclient->add_links( $xpath_expression ); # or
$webclient->add_links( $css_selector );
```

It shouldn't be too difficult to cobble something together using Perl, LWP and XML::LibXML (HTML parser), but maybe you know of a tool that allows you to do just that so I don't need to reinvent it.

It doesn't have to be Perl, any other language is fine, too, and so is a ready-made program that has the flexibility required for this job.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question.

Comment: @ikegami - Being precise, or dense, eh? I wrote "maybe you know of a tool that allows you to do just that", but I admit I forgot the question mark.

Comment: No, there is no no existing tool that matches your extremely precise custom requirements, and you know that. But yeah, I am being dense. I an intentionally ignoring the only question I do hear ("Can you write my code for me?") for your benefit.

Comment: @ikegami - "I an intentionally ignoring the only question I do hear ("Can you write my code for me?") for your benefit." - Consider that the questions we *hear* (but which aren't there) might be a consequence of our outlook on life. But then, everyone can just have a bad day or a bad week. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the find_link function (and siblings) from [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aMechanize). It can use arbitrary criteria to find links including the "id" and "class" attributes.

Comment: I realize that this doesn't use XPath or CSS selectors but you may not need them to get the job done.

Comment: Thanks, `WWW::Mechanize` was the first thing I looked at. Unfortunately, its link spec does not take the position of the link in the DOM into account; it only looks at the link tag and doesn't have any information concerning the tag's place in the doc. It uses [HTML::Parser](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::Parser), which doesn't build a DOM, so the info I need is not there. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I considered that but it wasn't 100% clear to me without a sample of the HTML that you needed to restrict the link search to subsets of the DOM. Check out the [script Adam Gotch made](http://perlbuzz.com/2011/11/finding-a-lost-dogs-owner-with-perl-and-wwwmechanize.html) to combine WWW::Mechanize with [HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath)

Answer (score 2):

[Mojo::UserAgent](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Mojo%3a%3aUserAgent) returns stuff that understands CSS3 selectors or XPath. For instance, I just showed an example in [Painless RSS processing with Mojo](http://blogs.perl.org/users/brian_d_foy/2012/04/painless-rss-processing-with-mojo.html). I'm really enjoying this new(ish) web client stuff. Most everything I want is already there (no additional modules) and it's integrated very well.

Comment: Thanks - hadn't thought of using `Mojo::UserAgent` in a standalone fashion. But yes, why not?

Answer (score 1):

This might get you started in the right direction or lead you astray. Note that I first saved the page to a local file so as not to constantly download it while I was working on it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new;

$tree->parse_file('nmake-ref.html');

my @links = map { { $_->as_text => $_->attr('href') } }
            $tree->findnodes(q{//div[@class='sectionblock']/*/a});

for my $link (@links) {
    my ($entry, $url) = %{ $link };
    ($link->{ file } = "$entry.html" ) =~ s/[^A-Za-z_0-9.]+/_/g;
    system wget => qq{'$url'}, '-O', $link->{ file };
}
```